# What is the use of getFormActionUrl()?

Tags: magento2, blocks, forms, adminform

In **Magento2.1.10** I am trying to make admin grid module and found below function in given path

> \app\code\xyz\Grid\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\addrow.php

```
public function getFormActionUrl(){
        if ($this->hasFormActionUrl()) {
            return $this->getData('form_action_url');
        }

        return $this->getUrl('*/*/save');
}
```

How this method is used in Magento 2 form?

Answer (score 0):

From the [`Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Backend/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php#L16) I can see there is one method [`getFormActionUrl()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Backend/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php#L177) and it is used by [`getSaveUrl()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Backend/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php#L167) so it used to get form save URL.